# Convert Array to serialize like string

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a Array like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Select one
    [1] => FB
    [2] => RM
    [3] => Joey
    [4] => Isaac
    [5] => Christina
    [6] => James
    [7] => Armando
    [8] => Kent
    [9] => Tyler
    [10] => Michael
    [11] => Dylan
    [12] => Ryan
)
```

I want to convert it to `0:None;1:FB;2:RM;3:Joey;4:Isaac;5:Christina;6:James;7:Armando;8:Kent;9:Tyler;10:Michael;11:Dylan`

I can do it using `FOR` loop and using `IF`, But I want to know the shortest way or is there any function available.
Any reference will be helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `serialize()`  doesnt work for you ?

Comment: I want that as string like mention up. nope `serialize` is not working.

Comment: @Eknoes I don't think it's duplicate.

Comment: key value pair, simple use `array_map()` with `implode()`, And there are no such functions or methods that your 'Select One' changed to None, You need to use `IF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
$output = implode(';', array_map(
    function ($v, $k) { return $k.":".$v; },
    $data,
    array_keys($data)
));
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok you should have submitted an answer instead of comment

Comment: No need to submit an answer, There is an answer which solve the problem.

Comment: @FrayneKonok upvote for your comment, actually i didn't see your comment before answering this

Comment: @VaraPrasad, Its okey.